# IdentityServer4 + ASP.NET Identity User Management

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

Here are the projects at play.

- IdentityServer4 (one instance)
- ASP.NET Identity (one instance)
- Multiple Independent Clients

What is the approach to take to make sure users of each client are independent to that client? Meaning that user of client A should not be able to login to client B.

I would like to keep one instance of IdentityServer4/ASP.NET Identity. Is this built in out of the box or do I need to customize and how would that look like?

I'd appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Application table with the application that are available.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then. in your IsActiveAsync method in a custom ProfileService check to see which users have access. I used companies as the discriminator and then added a CompanyId to my AspNetUser table but you could create a table called [UserApplication] with the user ids to do the same thing.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CompanyApplication](
    [CompanyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CompanyApplication] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CompanyId] ASC,
    [ApplicationId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Create a custom profile service to take care of the filtering.

```
// Custom profile service
public class CustomService : IProfileService
{
    ...

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var userClaim = context.Subject.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "sub");

        if (userClaim != null)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userClaim.Value);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var applications = FindCompanyApplications(user);
                context.IsActive = applications.Any(s => s == context.Client.ClientId);
            }
            else
                context.IsActive = false;
        }

    }
    private List<String> FindCompanyApplications(SpUser user)
    {
        return (
            // I named this CompanyApplicationRefs 
            // but comes from CompanyApplication table
            from ca in db.CompanyApplicationRefs 
            join a in db.Applications on ca.ApplicationId equals a.Id
            where ca.CompanyId == user.CompanyId
            select a.Description
        ).ToList();
    }
}
```

There are other things that need to be done like creating your custom identity user and registering the profile service for IdentityServer as well as dependency injection for the service.

But this should get you on the right track.